# Convert from pandas dataframe to LabeledPoint RDD

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running some tests on a very simple dataset which consists basically of numerical data. 
It can be found [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/poker/poker-hand-training-true.data).

I was working with pandas, numpy and scikit-learn just fine but when moving to Spark I couldn't set up the data in the correct format to input it to a Decision Tree.

I was doing this which didn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/poker/poker-hand-training-true.data')

raw_data = sc.parallelize(df)

train_dataset = raw_data.map(lambda line: line.split(","))\
                            .map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[10], np.array([float(x) for x in line[0:10]])))
```

I kept getting `IndexError: list index out of range` when trying to do access `line` inside the map function.

I only managed to get it to work when I actually downloaded the file and changed the code as follows:

```
raw_data = sc.textFile('.../datasets/poker-hand-training.data')

train_dataset = raw_data.map(lambda line: line.split(","))\
                            .map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[10], np.array([float(x) for x in line[0:10]])))
```

If I don't want to download the dataset, is it possible to get the data ready directly from pandas dataframes using `read_csv`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to first convert `Pandas DataFrame` into `Spark DataFrame`. You can use [sqlContext.createDataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) method to do that.

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/poker/poker-hand-training-true.data', names=['S1','C1','S2','C2','S3','C3','S4','C4','S5','C5','class'])
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Now you can use this Dataframe to get your training dataset.

```
train_dataset  = s_df.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[10], x[:10])).collect()
```

Comment: Best one-liner to convert!